# Expo: change directory

Tags: react-native, expo

After running the command `eas build --platform android` the expo cli is showing following info:

```
Created @MyAccount/LoremIpsum (​https://expo.dev/accounts/myAccount/projects/LoremIpsum ) on Expo
```

how do I change to another directory i.e `@MyAccount/xyz` so that i can use preexisting keystore

Answer (score 0):

In the app.json change the slug to the existing directory.